# wso2 identity server - extending AbstractUserStoreManager class and doAuthenticate() method

Tags: wso2

I have extended the AbstractUserStoreManager class and have override code in the doAuthenticate() method to do a custom authentication process. The doAuthenticate method is correctly returning true when I log in w/ my credentials.

However, the wso2 identity server user management console is still throwing a login failed message. (i.e. the CarbonAuthenticationUtil.onFailedAdminLogin method is being called).

It may be a issue w/ not doing the work to show this user is in an admin role.

However, I put some logging in each method to see what is firing. Yet I am not seeing any methods that check roles being fired after the doAuthenticate() method is fired.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the log running at DEBUG verbosity:

```
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,669] DEBUG -  getRequestAddressingRequirementParameterValue: got value from MessageContext [MessageContext: logID=cd1ae48ec92e8ccb25cd294c255c695acb01113f991655f8], value: 'null' {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,669] DEBUG -  getRequestAddressingRequirementParameterValue: value: 'null' {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,669] DEBUG -  getRequestAddressingRequirementParameterValue: value: 'null' {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,670] DEBUG -  [MessageContext: logID=dd1ae48ec92e8ccb25cd294c255c695acb01113f991655f8] isReplyRedirected: ReplyTo is null. Returning false {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,670] DEBUG -  [MessageContext: logID=dd1ae48ec92e8ccb25cd294c255c695acb01113f991655f8] isReplyRedirected: ReplyTo is null. Returning false {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,670]  INFO -  isAuthenticated?: true {com.dg.rio.proxy.user.store.DGProxyReadOnlyUserStoreManager}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,670] DEBUG -  Post authenticator is called in IdentityMgtEventListener {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,670] DEBUG -  Post authenticator is called in IdentityMgtEventListener {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,671] DEBUG -  AUTHORIZATION_CACHE Memory cache hit, but element expired {net.sf.ehcache.Cache}
[2013-03-15 15:17:55,672] ERROR -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : null {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.isUserAuthorized(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:134)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin.login(AuthenticationAdmin.java:107)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for IS 4.10 just came out (last week I think). I read the section for configuring external ldap and jdbc stores, it said to use a user name for an admin in the realm configuration (in user-mgt.xml).

```
                <AdminUser>
                 <UserName>MYADMINUSER</UserName>
```

Adding this user name with an arbitratory (backdoor) password, does allow the admin user to authenticate with a valid password. i.e.

if doAuthenticate returns true, he will authenticate. If false, he gets rejected as expected.

Seems a little hoaky, but glad to see it work.